# How to make a categorical variable based on whether a time object falls between two other time objects

Tags: r, datetime, time, datetime-conversion

I am trying to create a new categorical variable that shows whether an observation Time falls between dawn and dusk times gathered from `suncalc`. For example. All three variables currently class character. I have tried both `as.factor()` and `as.POSIXIt()` operators but haven't found the magic words yet.

```
#       Time     dawn     dusk
# 1 19:59:05 05:59:12 21:12:01
# 2 18:46:05 05:51:25 21:21:48
# 3 07:50:21 07:42:54 18:54:53
# 4 10:19:00 04:37:52 21:38:02
# 5 12:16:35 04:39:50 21:39:02
# 6 09:34:26 07:02:49 18:32:55
```

to make

```
#       Time     dawn     dusk     daynight
# 1 23:59:05 05:59:12 21:12:01        night
# 2 18:46:05 05:51:25 21:21:48          day
# 3 07:50:21 07:42:54 18:54:53          day
# 4 10:19:00 04:37:52 21:38:02          day
# 5 02:16:35 04:39:50 21:39:02        night
# 6 09:34:26 07:02:49 18:32:55          day
```

I have tried both several ifelse statements and `lubridate` functions but nothing seems to work. I am probably doing both those things wrong or I am just not thinking of something. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

disclaimer: first post on stackoverflow, if I am doing it wrong please tell me for any future posts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base R doesn't have a class for time only data, but the `chron` package does.

You can use the `times` function in the `chron` package along with an `ifelse`, like this...

```
#read data
x <- read.table(text = "
  Time     dawn     dusk
  23:59:05 05:59:12 21:12:01 
  18:46:05 05:51:25 21:21:48
  07:50:21 07:42:54 18:54:53
  10:19:00 04:37:52 21:38:02
  02:16:35 04:39:50 21:39:02
  09:34:26 07:02:49 18:32:55
", header = TRUE)

library(chron) #for times

#coerce character-formatted times to times (time-only) class
x$Time <- times(x$Time)
x$dawn <- times(x$dawn)
x$dusk <- times(x$dusk)

#use ifelse to assign conditional label
x$daynight <- with(x, ifelse(Time >= dawn & Time < dusk, "day", "night"))

#> x
#      Time     dawn     dusk daynight
#1 23:59:05 05:59:12 21:12:01    night
#2 18:46:05 05:51:25 21:21:48      day
#3 07:50:21 07:42:54 18:54:53      day
#4 10:19:00 04:37:52 21:38:02      day
#5 02:16:35 04:39:50 21:39:02    night
#6 09:34:26 07:02:49 18:32:55      day
```

See also relevant posts:

[Want only the time portion of a date-time object in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19460608/want-only-the-time-portion-of-a-date-time-object-in-r)

[Storing time without date but not as class character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26680499/storing-time-without-date-but-not-as-class-character)

Comment: That works! Thank you! Definitely need to remember that package.